# Use of \@item doesn't match its definition

Tags: errors

I get the following error message:

> ```
> ! Use of \@item doesn't match its definition. \@ifnextchar ...
> \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
>                                               #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f... l.23 ...t{a}{\Dfootnote{edA; a}} e}{\Bfootnote{G}}
>                                                / \\
> ```

when I run either pdflatex or xelatex on this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noeledmac]{ledmac}
\setcounter{firstlinenum}{2}
\setcounter{linenumincrement}{2}  
\noendnotes
\setlength{\ledrsnotewidth}{4em}
\footparagraph{A}
\footparagraph{B}
\footparagraph{C}
\footparagraph{D}

\title{Nyayamanjari: 7th Ahnika}
\author{Alex \textsc{Watson} \\
\texttt{alex\_watson\_uk@yahoo.co.uk}}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\beginnumbering

\pstart
\begin{verse}
 t \ledrightnote{edA 148} p \edtext{\edtext{a}{\Dfootnote{edA; a}} e}{\Bfootnote{G}} / \\

\end{verse}
\pend
\end{document}
```

What's causing the problem?

Comment: `\Dfootnote` seems to be fragile: using `\protect\Dfootnote` avoids the error, though I'm not sure if the output is as-expected!